# How can I mock an attribute of a class using the mock decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
#these classes live inside exchanges/impl/tse/mixins.py

class PacketContext: 
    capture_tstamp = None
    def __init__(self, capture_tstamp=None):
        self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp

class SubParserMixin(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.context = PacketContext()

    def on_packet(self, packet):
        self.context.capture_tstamp = packet.capture_timestamp
        self.parse_er_data(packet.payload)



#this mock test lives in another python file
from exchanges.impl.tse.mixins import PacketContext

@patch.object(PacketContext, 'capture_tstamp', 1655417400314635000)
def test_receive_timestamp(self):
    """
    test receive_timestamp is passed down correctly from PacketContext to on_packet()
    """
    assert self.context.capture_tstamp == 1655417400314635000
```

I am trying to mock the `self.capture_tstamp` attribute in the `PacketContext()` class.

But in the above, I am getting an error that says

```
    AssertionError: assert None == 1655417400314635000
E        +  where None = <exchanges.impl.tse.mixins.PacketContext object at 0x7fb324ac04c0>.capture_tstamp
E        +    where <exchanges.impl.tse.mixins.PacketContext object at 0x7fb324ac04c0> = <tests.unit.exchanges.tse.test_quote_write.TestTSE testMethod=test_receive_timestamp>.context
```

It seems very strange that the program is not recognising `PacketContext()`.

Comment: The title of you question is misleading.  Have you tried importing `exchanges`? Plus, your decorator is wrongly indented.

Comment: Indentation fixed, sorry

Comment: I do import the following `from exchanges.impl.tse.mixins import PacketContext`, but Pycharm says it is unused

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the patch.object decorator as below

```
class PacketContext:
    capture_tstamp = None
    def __init__(self, capture_tstamp=None):
        self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp
```

```
<import_PacketContext_here>

@patch.object(PacketContext, 'capture_tstamp', 1655417400314635000)
def test_receive_timestamp():
    test_instance = PacketContext()
    assert test_instance.capture_tstamp == 1655417400314635000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot VIkrant. 

I am getting the error: `AttributeError: <class 'exchanges.impl.tse.mixins.PacketContext'> does not have the attribute 'capture_tstamp'`. 
Not sure why I am getting this- I am importing the `PacketContext` from a different python script.

Comment: Like this: `from exchanges.impl.tse.mixins import PacketContext`

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing `self.context`

Comment: Of course, Let me add exactly what I have now to the question

Comment: I've made all the changes now and everything is up to date in my question!

Comment: I should add that all i am trying to test is that `self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp` is getting passed down to `self.context.capture_tstamp = packet.capture_timestamp`

Comment: @Patrick_Chong. It works fine now
`@patch.object(PacketContext, 'capture_tstamp', 1655417400314635000)`

just udpate the patch to this. Since capture_tstamp is not a function, we are not using return_value.

Please check and let me know. I am also updating my answer

Comment: @Patrick_Chong. The last argument says return_value=<our_value> since capture_tstamp is not a function. We must not specify return_value=<our_value> and just <our_value>

I have run this on my machine. it works fine. I am also posting an alternative solution. Because this might not worki if attribute is initialized in __init__.. You can simply modify your class as I have updated in my answer

Comment: @Patrick_Chong please have a look at my updated answer. You need to add a slight modification in PacketContext . You need to define the attribute at class level also. Now it will work fine

Comment: Vikrant, will adding the extra line to PacketContext have any effects on my code though? I don't mean in testing but when I run the actual code

Comment: No it wont have any effects. It just says that capture_tstamp is defined by default as None. That's anyway going to happen once __init__ is called. so It wont have any effects. You can safely use this.

Comment: Vikrant our code is different, I need to test that `self.context.capture_tstamp == 1655417400314635000`

Comment: I have a feeling I may have mocked the wrong object. Vikrant- do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set `self.capture_tstamp = 1655417400314635000` . Then test that  `assert self.context.capture_tstamp == 1655417400314635000`

Comment: If you run your code with `assert self.context.capture_tstamp == 1655417400314635000` it will fail

Comment: Yes I think we need to create our object inside the test. since we are patching the attribute at the test level. 

Maybe that is why `test_instance=PatchContext()` works and self.context doesn't work ..

If you want to patch it for the whole class, then maybe you can do the patch at class level.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks that does make some sense- I've always preferred to create mock objects over the decorator anyway, let me try it